# Xamarin Forms GeolocatorPlugin Emulator only

Tags: xamarin.forms, geolocation

For some reason Xamarin forms upgrade or GeoLocation plugin upgrade seems to have broken code that's been running for a long time. Basically when I run the code on an emulator it works perfect. As soon as I run it on a real device it only works slightly or not at all. I'm using Always permission and verified it's correct. The code was build using GeoLocation version 3.0.4 hasn't changed. Currently using version 4.2.0. It was build somewhere around version 1.4 of Xamarin.Forms if memory serves me. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "works slightly or not at all"? Do you have any error in the console output or exception?

Comment: No exceptions anywhere...  I'm using message service to send the speed and distance to the front end and it will most often show the first location update then it won't show anything after most of the time. Occasionally it will start again. I use ACR Dialog to show if exception hits it never does. I have no idea how to get an error on a console when driving around. I wish I had a way to fake the location on a real device as it works perfectly on emulator.

Comment: What happens when executing locator.GetPositionAsync ?

Comment: locator.GetPositionAsync works perfect never an issue.

Comment: I would say that the problem is not linked to the update of the Geolocation plugin, rather than something of how you use MessagingCenter or how you show the position..

Comment: I start with WireDriveService in AppDelegate

Comment: I removed the message service code and left the part where it uploads the location data to my server. Didn't receive any data. The strange thing nothing has changed in the view model, drive service, or UI in around 1 year. It must be due to a change in Xamarin Forms, Geo Locator Plugin, or some other related library.

Comment: Looks like I might have figured it out. Before version 4 we didn't have ListnerSettings and we had to handle background in our own background service. I removed all my background code and called it directly and so far it's working perfect. It looks like this new AllowBackgroundUpdates flag handles everything and my old background service code was interfering with this new way of doing it. Thank you very much for taking your time to help...